# jQuery Adds Extra '#' to URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I noticed sometimes that when I use jQuery, a extra '#' gets added to the end of my URL after a jQuery function is called.  For example, the URL 'www.mywebsite.com' will change to 'www.mywebsite.com/#' once a jQuery function is initialized.  The same for 'www.testsite.com/users.php', is changed to 'www.testsite.com/users.php#'.

Why does jQuery add the '#'?

Comment: Are you clicking any link on your page that has empty or no href specified? If so that's normal

Comment: This is like saying "When I drive a car how do you keep spike strips from popping my tires?". What kind of driving are you doing here? So define "use jQuery". What usage (meaning what code) do you run that when you click an element the result is a `#` on the url? This shouldn't really happen if you are doing things right.

Comment: Alex, I have no idea what you are rambling about.  You seem to be confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your function is running from a link onclick, you need to use event.preventDefault()

See http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Answer (score 1):

Usually this is because you have a dummy link with a jQuery click handler.  It's common to see links with an href of `#` that are only used to trigger some JavaScript.

```
<a href="#" class="button">Go</a>
```

Resolve this easily by making a habit of calling `e.preventDefault()` in your click handlers:

```
$(function() {
    $(".button").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        ...
    });
});
```

You can also use `return false`, but that has the added effect of stopping event propagation.  I like to add `e.stopPropagation()` explicitly if I also want that effect.  It makes the code and it's intended effect more explicit and clear for future developers (or myself in 6 months).

Comment: "Progressive enhancement" suggests you e.preventDefault() as the _last_ statement in your click block. The hope is the link is real (not just #), and invokes server side processing that works with any browser. The JavaScript is sugar that lets it happen on the client side, unless something goes wrong.

Comment: @DawsonToth - Fair enough. That risks `e.preventDefault()` not being called if the function can ever return early.  Besides, if your `href` is `#`, you clearly aren't using progressive enhancement.  Maybe graceful degradation.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you're getting this when handling a click event. If you don't want that happens, just add `event.preventDefault()` or `return false` at the end in event handler function.